# Указать в функции, что аргументов является список с элементами определенного типа данных

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я знаю, что я могу указать в питоне, что аргумент является списком, вот так:

```
def func(arg: list)
```

Но что, если я должен получать список только с целыми числами? Могу ли я как-то сделать это? Может быть это можно сделать, используя массивы numpy?

Comment: `typing.List[int]`

Comment: не "лист", а "список".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать аннотацию типов для указания типа элементов, которые должны присутствовать в списке. Следующий код определяет функцию, которая принимает список с целочисленными элементами:

```
import typing

def func(arg: typing.List[int]) -> None:
    pass
```

Comment: `def func(arg: list[int]) -> None:``

Comment: Ну строго говоря данную функцию можно вызвать с любым аргументом в arg, даже если это будет вообще не список, и никакой ошибки при этом не возникнет. Можно сказать что аннотации носят рекомендательный характер. Я к тому что формулировка "принимает список ТОЛЬКО с целочисленными элементами" слишком строгая и не совсем соответствует действительности.

Comment: да совсем не соответствует действительности такая формулировка.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa да, я немного углубился в эту тему. Спасибо за рекомендацию!

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю, что начиная с Python3.9 можно писать так (т. е. без `typing.List`, а просто с `list`):

```py
def func(arg: list[int]) -> None:
    pass
```

А если нужно несколько типов, то так:

- Начиная с Python3.10:

  ```py
  def func(arg: list[int | float]) -> None:
      pass
  ```
- Начиная с Python3.9:

  ```py
  from typing import Union

  def func(arg: list[Union[int, float]]) -> None:
      pass
  ```
- До Python3.9:

  ```py
  from typing import List, Union

  def func(arg: List[Union[int, float]]) -> None:
      pass
  ```

Comment: эта функция появилась в 3.9